# how to disable the SwipeMenuLIstView to Swipe based on position?

Tags: android, listview, swiperefreshlayout

i am using Swipe menu list View from the Github
https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView

According to my project requirement i need to stop  list View to Swipe based on position.
For example i want to stop the list item to swipe on the position 2
how  would i do that?

```html
mListView.setOnSwipeListener(new SwipeMenuListView.OnSwipeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSwipeStart(int position) {
            if (positon == 2) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you are not Allow to Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipeEnd(int position) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: You can handle this inside the `SwipeMenuListView`. So instead of just compiling the dependency in the gradle, you have to import the project so that you can edit it. Put a break point on `onTouchEvent` inside `SwipeMenuListView` and you will understand what to do.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView#create-different-menu) .It essentially says that you can use different menuitems for different positions. So, in your case you can return a different type for position 2 and remove all the items using menu creator.